# Mac OS - Open links from Chrome PWAs in default browser instead (Safari)

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome

I prefer Safari as my default browser for Mac OS but use Gmail's progressive web app (backed by chrome) for emails to get offline functionality etc.

Is there a way to get links clicked on in Gmail / Chrome to open in Safari instead?

Comment: Hey,
Did you find any solution for this?